# Removing animations from navigationBar to stop completion handler

Tags: ios, animation

I'm animating the change of my navigationBar's height.

```
let bar = navigationController?.navigationBar

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { bar?.frame.size.height = 79 }) {
    if $0 { print("completed") }
}
```

For simplicity, I'm using a standard `UIView` animation, but in my original code I'm using the option: `allowUserInteraction`.

To prevent the completion to print out "completed", normally I remove the animations from the animating object:

```
object.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

This works when it's a normal `UIView` and the completion handler won't print anything. But in the case of a navigation bar it seems this isn't working:

```
bar?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Having "removed" all the animations, the console still prints out:

```
completed
```

What's the difference with a navigation bar, why can't I seem to remove the animations to stop the completion handler?